# Kafka sink connector Error Executing stage 'TASK_PUT'

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, protobuf-java

Hi guys i am writing a sink connector to push data from a protobuf topic to database.
The connector status seems running but when checking logs i see the following error and no data is pushed to the database table.

```
[2023-03-21 22:26:47,367] ERROR Error encountered in task 32red-all-deposit-proto-to-mssql-flat-test-postgres-3. Executing stage 'TASK_PUT' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask', where consumed record is {topic='STR_32RED_ALL_DEPOSITS_FLAT', partition=3, offset=116, timestamp=1679399268996, timestampType=CreateTime}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
```

The proto topic i had has following sample data

```json
{
  "EVENTSEQUENCENUMBER": "31851094",
  "GAMINGSYSTEMID": 323,
  "ROUTERID": 3,
  "USERNAME": "nonapplicable",
  "USERID": "1516780",
  "PRODUCTID": 380,
  "SESSIONPRODUCTID": 380,
  "SESSIONID": 190985932,
  "CURRENCYISOCODE": "GBP",
  "OPERATORCURRENCYISOCODE": "GBP",
  "PLAYERTOOPERATOREXCHANGERATE": 1.0,
  "DEPOSITAMOUNT": 10.0,
  "DEPOSITTYPE": "Ecash",
  "DEPOSITMETHOD": "Pay_Pal",
  "BALANCEAFTERDEPOSIT": 10.16,
  "ECASHPROCESSORID": 160,
  "ECASHPROCESSORDESCRIPTION": "Pay_Pal",
  "ISSUCCESS": 1,
  "UTCEVENTTIME": "2023-03-21 11:47:25.5677383",
  "TICKSEVENTTIME": "638149960455677383",
  "COUNTRYLONGCODE": "GBR",
  "LANGUAGECODE": "EN",
  "SESSIONCOUNTRYLONGCODE": "GBR",
  "NUMDEPOSITSTOTAL": 2036,
  "TOTALDEPOSITSAMOUNT": 20901.0,
  "TRANSACTIONID": 11369506,
  "TRANSACTIONUTCDATETIME": "2023-03-21 11:47:25.510",
  "TRANSACTIONNUMBER": "380_11369506",
  "TRANSACTIONSTATUSID": 1,
  "TRANSACTIONSTATUS": "Accept",
  "EVENTID": 6026,
  "EVENTNAME": "Pay_Pal_Transaction - Automatic Update",
  "TRANSACTIONEVENTTYPEID": 1,
  "TRANSACTIONEVENTTYPE": "Purchase",
  "ECASHREQUESTTIME": "2023-03-21 11:47:08.303",
  "PLAYERGROUP": "7cf2209c-1500-495b-9e80-ffc2ae4a9902"
}
```

And following is my sink connector configuration :
It is reading from this topic and trying to write to the table in the connector, the table will be autocreated on demand if it doesn't exist.

```json
{
    "name": "32red-all-deposit-proto-to-mssql-flat-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "table.name.format": "RealTimeEvents.connector.SEG_32RED_ALL_DEPOSITS_PROTO",
        "connection.password": "password",
        "topics": "STR_32RED_ALL_DEPOSITS_FLAT",
        "tasks.max": "4",
        "batch.size": "100",
        "max.retries": "3",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "errors.log.enable": true,
        "connection.user": "RealTimeEvents",
        "name": "32red-all-deposit-proto-to-mssql-flat-test",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://BEL1DATAOPSDV01.data32red.com:1433;Catalog=RealTimeEvents;databaseName=RealTimeEvents",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode" : "none",
        "pk.fields" : "none",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://cp-schema-registry.d2-dev.aws.kindredgroup.com",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location": "/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/cp-kafka-connect.d2-dev.aws.kindredgroup.com.truststore.jks",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password": "${dir:/etc/kafka-connect/secrets:cp-kafka-connect.d2-dev.aws.kindredgroup.com.TrustStorePass}",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location": "/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/cp-kafka-connect.d2-dev.aws.kindredgroup.com.keystore.jks",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password": "${dir:/etc/kafka-connect/secrets:cp-kafka-connect.d2-dev.aws.kindredgroup.com.KeyStorePass}",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.key.password": "${dir:/etc/kafka-connect/secrets:cp-kafka-connect.d2-dev.aws.kindredgroup.com.KeyPass}",
        "errors.log.include.messages": true
    }
}
```

Comment: [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You might get a more detailed error from /status API endpoint of connect server